# Best way to count successful curl fetches

Tags: php, curl, counter, http-status-codes

I'm looking for the best way to count successful curl fetches, i sort of just pieced things together here, it works but its a bit slow, is there any faster alternative? I'm running/refreshing the script over one minute and trying to determine how many times everything is pulled successfully within that minute.

```
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200) {
$counter = @file_get_contents('count.txt');
$counter++;
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $counter);
}
```

Comment: The slow part here will be the `curl` bit, not the writing to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed it up, you can use multithreaded curl: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php

Comment: You mean to use curl to pull and write the count.txt as well?